# Are compact Lie algebras necessarily compact as a set of matrices?

Tags: lie-algebras, compactness

I'm reading through a paper and came across something confusing; my limited experience with Lie theory is a bit of a hindrance:

The author starts with a compact set of matrices (in the usual Euclidean topology) $\{A_i\}\subset \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and generates a Lie algebra with Levi decomposition $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{s}\oplus\mathfrak{r}$. Under the assumption that $\mathfrak{s}$ is a compact Lie algebra, I'm curious about the compactness of the set $\{e^{-s}r_i e^{s}\,:\,s\in \mathfrak{s}, A_i = s_i + r_i\}$. Clearly the set of $r_i$ is compact (in the usual Euclidean topology), but it seems to me that as a set, $\mathfrak{s}$ could possibly be non-compact (in Euclidean sense) even though it's declared a compact Lie algebra (since in my reading of compact Lie algebras, I haven't come across any of the familiar "closed and bounded" type assertions).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Here is a simple example: take $\mathbb{R}$ as a trivial one dimensional lie algebra (so Lie Bracket is zero ) then the map $e^{2\pi. i x}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^{1}$ makes $S^{1}$ the unit circle into a compact lie goup.

Comment: DBS: I like that example, thanks. So, being the Lie algebra of a compact Lie group, would $\mathbb{R}$ be considered a compact Lie algebra?

Comment: I wouldn't say that. A Lie group gives rise to a Lie algebra where as going from a Lie algebra to a Lie group is little ambiguous. For example you could have taken the usual exponential lmap $e^{x}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and arrive at the real non-compact lie group $\mathbb{R}_{+}$. Technically mine is not an example because we are dealing with "tori" but this is not an isolated phenomenon and leads up to compact real forms etc etc.

Comment: It is best to think that a compact Lie algebra is the lie algebra of a compact lie group. But the same Lie algebra structure can also give rise to a non-compact group so it is not an intrinsic property of the lie algebra itself. A Lie algebra is a vector space (over reals/complex) so it is never compact. However if the group that it gives rise to is compact then we have an action of a compact group of a vector space (by the adjoint action) and hence nice things can be said about this action (see wikipedia).

Comment: Much clearer now, thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compact *Lie groups* are topological groups whose topology is compact. A compact Lie algebra is the Lie algebra of a compact Lie group, therefore the name "compact". Lie algebras are vector spaces, and all finite-dimensional Lie algebras are linear, i.e., subalgebra of the Lie algebra of matrices.
For Lie algebras "compact" just means that they are reductive with negative-definite Killing form.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I understand you correctly, then assuming $\mathfrak{s}$ is a compact Lie algebra, it's Lie group (the set $\{e^{st}\, : \, s\in \mathfrak{s}, t\geq 0\}$ with matrix multiplication) is compact (in the usual sense), thus the set in question (\{e^{-s}r_i e^{s}\, : \, s\in \mathfrak{s}, A_i = s_i + r_i \}$) would be compact (in the usual sense).

Does this seem right to you?

Answer (score 1):

Lie algebras are vector spaces, in this case subspaces of the vector space of matrices. Over the real and complex numbers, vector spaces are never compact unless they are trivial.

Comment: Of course! Thanks for pointing that out in an easy to understand manner. Then it follows that the set in question could not be compact in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ unless $\mathfrak{s}$ is trivial.

Edits: English

Comment: Actually, in light of Burde's answer, I suppose it's still possible for the set in question to be compact in the usual topology if the set $\{e^s\,:\,s\in \mathfrak{s}\}$ is.

Comment: @Ironbeard the exponential is often compact.